# Storing inputs? (java)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, user-input

if I use a `scanner` to read system input, how do i store the input in one string?

So far I have something like this.

```
Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
String name = user_input.next();
```

If in the `terminal` I type, `"Bob Saget", name = "Bob"`. I want `name = "Bob Saget"`
Can anyone give me detailed instructions, if they involve eliminating `white space` or using `tokenizers` or something?

Comment: Although an easy (and thus not very helpful) question, I wish much more question are asked like this: A good explanation and a minimal amount of code that is very clear.

Answer (score 1):

Use `nextLine` instead of `next` in order to read the entire input line into your `name` variable :

```
String name = user_input.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `user_input.nextLine()` method , it reads till ENTER key is pressed

Answer (score 1):

Use the `nextLine();` method. The `next();` method only reads the first token, the input until the first space (separator).

```
nextLine();
```

reads the entire line.